# Datastore or local files for AppEngine app

Tags: database, google-app-engine

I am designing a simple webapp which organises daily bible readings to the user every day.
The readings are on average about 300-400 words per day.

So for example user1 signed up today, so readings of day1 are returned to them. User2 signed up a week later but it is still day1 for them so they get readings of day1 again and so on..

I am expecting about 100 users at launch with possible expansion later.

Now there's two approaches that I can think of for doing this:

1) Store entire bible in the datastore (about 30,000 verses in total) and query readings of everyday (~50 verses) while possibly caching already queried days as files.

2) Have a local script store readings of each day in a file (so 365 files in total) and render the file and return it to the user without touching the datastore.

Bear in mind that the year after that there will be different readings so if I went with option 2 I'd have to upload a new set of files.

I don't really know what I want and how effecient every option would be.
Any ideas? Am I missing something else?

Comment: Question isn't really suited to SO.  But some quick points.  You can't write the filesystem, so caching will be memcache and datastore.  If you go down the path of files you will still probably need to keep metadata about each file in the datastore to allow you to evolve the system. You might as well keep all the data in the datastore.  Just my 2c worth. This sort of data and the amount of data you are extracting is not going to be slow or expensive on appengine for the sort of numbers you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how 'dynamic' you want your site to be.  If you're strictly returning one verse per page, it'll be very cost efficient to pre-render all your pages as HTML.

When you get a request from a user, you could fetch the user entity when they access the page, calculate the appropriate verse to show them, and then redirect them to the verse page.  As an added benefit, if the verse pages are static, they can be cached well on Google's edge cache, and you wouldn't have any cost in terms of serving the pages.

However, if you want to dynamically create your page, this mechanism isn't as beneficial.

Generally speaking though, since the verses aren't a dataset that's going to change, it'll be cheaper to store it as a file and index the verses yourself.

Comment: Thank you for an insightful answer. It is very easy for me to write a script that will create all the pages so it looks like I'll go with static pages.

Answer (score 0):

Abstracting this a bit, users have a sequence of items to process. I'm not clear from the question whether readers process at their own rate, or at a constant rate that's offset by the reader's start date. Either way, though, is straightforward to handle.

You need an entity that represents the user. For this to work, you'll need to require that the user logs in. Then, you can user their email address as the key to this entity. If users progress through readings at their own rate (but, say, no faster than one per day), then you can record the date of the most recent visit, and the index of the item (reading) that they were presented on that date. When they visit on a new date, the index advances, and they get a new item (reading).

If readings are fixed based on the user's start date, then the entity needs to record their start date, so that you can determine the reading by calculating the difference between the current date and their start date (adjusting accordingly for a 1-based index).

Both ways assume that you have the readings indexed by number, either by key value, or by some indexed field.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this was not my question.
I am not talking about storing users data I am talking about storing readings data. I want to display the readings as HTML in the webapp and asking what is the best way to store them.

Comment: Either of the two ways works, as does a hybrid approach of uploading a years's worth of readings in once file, then having a background task break that into individual datastore entities. My guess is that this approach would balance convenience with fast access.